# How to handle geometry field in PostGIS with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, geometry, postgis, typeorm

I am using TypeORM which is connected to a local postgis instance running from [this image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/)

This is my entity file (`Geometry` comes from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/geojson)):

```js
@Entity()
export class Port {
  @Column({ type: 'geometry' })
  geometry: Geometry;
}
```

Here I can see that TypeORM succeeded in creating the database.

[image: (screenshot from pgadmin)]

However when I try to insert any port, TypeORM throws:

```
QueryFailedError: unknown GeoJSON type
```

Data I am trying to insert is in WKT format. For example

```
"POINT(18.5478833 54.5353333)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK it's not really well supported https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I ended up using is:

**Entity**

```
@Column({
  type: 'geometry',
  srid: 4326,
})
geometry: string;
```

**Service**

```
public async create(version: CreateTDTO): Promise<T> {
  return this.baseZoneVersionRpository
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .values({
      ...(version as any),
      geometry: () => `ST_GeomFromText('${version.geometry}', 4326)`,
    })
    .execute() as any;
}
```

*Note that this one expects input data in a WKT format.*

*Unfortunately I didn't find a way to get rid of `any`*

**Change format coming from database**

I am not sure why but my `PostGIS` database returns data in `GeoJSON` format by default and I haven't been able to change it through the `TypeORM`. There is a way however to transform entities using `TypeORM`'s `transformer`.

```
@Column({
  type: 'geometry',
  srid: 4326,
  transformer: {
    to: (something) => something,
    from: transformFromGeoJSONToYourFormat,
  },
})
geometry: string;
```

Library I found particularly helpfull for changing geometry formats was https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkx