# How to save WKT to postgres column with geometry data type using typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, postgis, geojson, wkt

I have a table with a geom column which has the datatype of geometry. I need to save data into this table and the request being sent has the type wkt for this column. Currently there are some existing rows in the table with data in this format:

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON((-82.42186119969756 35.50904833429925,-82.41310709710558 35.5138338218795,-82.40448173131567 35.50461189763692,-82.41851404282427 35.500629375676766,-82.42186119969756 35.509013402684445,-82.42186119969756 35.50904833429925))
```

Is the "SRID=4326" portion of the data autogenerated?

Currently I have the follow set up:

dto:

```
 @IsString()
 geom: string; //geometry
```

entity:

```
@Column('geometry', {spatialFeatureType: 'Polygon', srid: 4326 })
geom: string;
```

And I and inserting the data like this, with dto.geom as a wtk string:

```
create(dto: CreatePlaceDto): Promise<number> {        
    return <any>this.repository
      .insert(dto)
      .then((data) => data.identifiers[0][Object.keys(data.identifiers[0])[0]])
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
```

When I send through a request, I get the `QueryFailedError: unknown GeoJSON type` error. When checking the raw sql query from the logs, it looks like the that the wkt is getting an extra set of quotes. And typeorm is trying to convert a geojson from to geom. I think i'd need typeorm to use ST_GeomFromText right? Since wkt isn't geojson.

```
INSERT INTO "place"("customerId", "geom", "industry", "createdAt", "updatedAt") 
VALUES ($1, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($2), 4326)::geometry, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) 
RETURNING "placeId", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
-- PARAMETERS: [13,"\"POLYGON ((-82.42186119969756 35.50904833429925, -82.41310709710558 35.5138338218795, -82.40448173131567 35.50461189763692, -82.41851404282427 35.500629375676766, -82.42186119969756 35.509013402684445, -82.42186119969756 35.50904833429925))\"","industry1"]
```

Am I correct in typing geom as string in dto and entity? How do I get the format with `"SRID=4326;POLYGON((-8 etc etc"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeORM doesn't support WKT as transport format for PostgreSQL/PostGIS; the native driver enforces the GeoJSON format (note that `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` supports parsing of individual `geometry` members of GeoJSON *Feature*s only).

Instead of relying on the DTO *repository* mapping, you can work with a `QueryStringBuilder` and directly influence parameter handling in the `INSERT` SQL statement:

```
await dataSource
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(<Entity>)
  .values({
    <columns>: <values>,
    geom: () =>
      `ST_GeomFromText('${<WKT_string>}', 4326)`,
      // or `'SRID=4326;${<WKT_string>}'`,
  })
  .execute()
```

*Taken and altered from the [docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/insert-query-builder#raw-sql-support); see e.g.*

- *https://stackoverflow.com/a/72866248/6782776*

*for a more generic IRL example, and a note about natively supported format transformations between WKT and GeoJSON as an alternative.*

---

If all you *ever* do is insertions you can probably get away with declaring the entities' column type as `string` - PostGIS defines implicit string casting for its `GEOMETRY` type and should handle the import correctly.

---

The `SRID=4326` part is a PostGIS specific extension to the WKT type (EWKT), which has no notion of CRS - the respective I/O functions are `ST_GeomFromEWKT` and `ST_AsEWKT`, respectively. The auto-cast mentioned above can handle EWKT, too.